# How to port forward on an ATT Router/Modem?

Tags: ssh, router, port-forwarding

I am trying to open port 2222 for an open-ssh server on my linux machine.

I am able to log into it just fine from my local IP address.

`sudo systemctl status` returns:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-10-10 19:25:19 PDT; 34min ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 9445 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 9446 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 19025)
     Memory: 3.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─9446 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups

Oct 10 19:25:19 jacob-desktop systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Oct 10 19:25:19 jacob-desktop sshd[9446]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
Oct 10 19:25:19 jacob-desktop sshd[9446]: Server listening on :: port 2222.
Oct 10 19:25:19 jacob-desktop systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Oct 10 19:49:54 jacob-desktop sshd[9648]: Accepted publickey for jacob from 192.168.1.220 port 53539 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:9DMi>
Oct 10 19:49:54 jacob-desktop sshd[9648]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user jacob by (uid=0)
```

But according to https://www.portchecktool.com/ my port 2222 is closed. My att port config is as follows:

[This one doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZGux.png)

What is so frustrating is that a port I opened using a different tool within the modem works, as shown below:
[This one works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbz56.png)

I don't see why port 22 should be open and work whereas port 2222 does not.

Is Att's modem bad, or am I making some error I don't see?

Thank anyone who helps with this, I've been ripping out my hair for months on various server-building attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I realized my issue was that though I had successfully setup a custom service, I never added it. There is a dropdown menu shown below which is required for the port forward to take effect.

[the missing peice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUTvU.png)

Clicking this menu, choose the new port forward, and then the device on your machine which the port should be forwarded to does the trick.

Rather than deleting this message, thought I would answer it because I'm sure lots of people use bad ATT routers.